# Trying to aggregate a query on data that has already been aggregated - not sure the best approach to use

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading data from an Excel spreadsheet, and I am able to narrow down the results to a specific date range using the following method, below.  As you can see it returns only results matching the date range criteria that I prescribed and returns info from each of the three columns: "Date of inquiry Receipt", "Office" and "LocationType".  However, what I wish to do is also calculate the total number of each unique value existing  in the resulting "office" column. For example I need to find out in my spreadsheet that for all data less than or equal to 2021-04-04 there are the following counts:  Central = 18  , Central West = 12 , East = 5, South = 3

If I were using good old fashioned SQL query language could I could use a single command that would be kind of like:
"SELECT 'Office' from 2021_AutoReport.xlsx WHERE 'Date of inquery Receipt' <= '2021-04-04', JOIN OUTTER for SUM(Central), SUM(Central West), SUM(South), SUM(East)  ....I'm not a SQL query pro, but hopefully you understand what I am trying to do and can advise how to do it by using dataframe queries?
Thanks so much for your help!

Example of what I have so far....just need to know how the approach to answer my question:

```py
df =pd.read_excel("2021_AutoReport.xlsx")
myfilteredInfo= df[df['Date of inquiry Receipt'] <= '2021-04-04']
print(myfilteredInfo)
```

..... Result:

```
 Date of inquiry Receipt          Office  LocationType
2               2021-01-04      Central   Laboratory  
3               2021-02-23      Central                 Farm   
4               2021-02-24      Central   Laboratory  
5               2021-02-24      Central   Laboratory  
6               2021-02-24      Central   Laboratory  
7               2021-02-26  Central West           SalesOffice   
8               2021-03-02      Central   Laboratory  
9               2021-03-03  Central West               Other   
10              2021-03-03  Central West           SalesOffice   
11              2021-03-04      Central   Laboratory  
12              2021-03-04      Central   Laboratory  
13              2021-03-08      Central   Laboratory  
14              2021-03-08           South               Other   
15              2021-03-09  Central West  Laboratory  
16              2021-03-11      Central   Laboratory  
17              2021-03-11  Central West               Other   
18              2021-03-16            East  Laboratory  
19              2021-03-16            East  Laboratory  
20              2021-03-19  Central West               Other   
21              2021-03-19  Central West  Laboratory  
22              2021-03-20            East  Laboratory  
23              2021-03-22      Central   Laboratory  
24              2021-03-22            East  Laboratory  
25              2021-03-23      Central                Other   
26              2021-03-24      Central   Laboratory  
27              2021-03-24  Central West  Laboratory  
28              2021-03-25      Central                Other   
29              2021-03-25  Central West               Other   
30              2021-03-25      Central   Laboratory  
31              2021-03-26           South  Laboratory  
32              2021-03-30      Central                Other   
33              2021-03-31  Central West  Laboratory  
34              2021-04-01           South               Other   
35              2021-04-01  Central West           SalesOffice   
36              2021-04-01      Central   Laboratory  
37              2021-04-01            East           SalesOffice   
38              2021-04-01      Central   Laboratory  
39              2021-04-01  Central West  Laboratory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... calculate the total number of each unique value existing in the resulting "office" column ...

This would do the work:

```py
>>> df.groupby('office').agg(numer_unique=('LocationType', 'count')
```

Comment: Thanks - your method nailed it.  I was looking for unique count of elements within the Office column itself so I adjusted it accordingly. Much appreciated and good stuff!  For the record, I ended up using something like this, based on your suggestion:  print(myfilteredInfo.groupby('Office').agg(numer_unique=('Office', 'count')))

Comment: I'm glad, that I helped. An Accept of the answer will be more than appreciated ;)

Comment: Done - thanks for your patience with my being a newb to this forum!  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

use the `value_counts` method ([Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)) for the column that you need (`Office`):

```
myfilteredInfo['Office'].value_counts()
```